# Caching private wordpress rest endpoints

Tags: wordpress, caching

I am trying to cache some private custom rest endpoints using WP Rest Cache and whenever i try it makes them public? Not sure if anyone has come across this but i need it to remain private in the cache to authenticated users.

```
register_rest_route( 'v1', 'get-report-summary/',array(
      'methods'  => 'GET',
      'callback' => 'get_report_summary',
      'permission_callback' => function () { 
          return is_user_logged_in();
      },
));

function get_report_summary(){

   $data = "Some code";

   $response = new WP_REST_Response($data);
   $response->set_status(200);

   return $response;
}
```

Adding the endpoint to the cache

```
function wprc_add_endpoint( $allowed_endpoints ) {
    if ( ! isset( $allowed_endpoints[ 'v1' ] ) || ! in_array( 'get-report-summary', $allowed_endpoints[ 'v1' ] ) ) {
        $allowed_endpoints[ 'v1' ][] = 'get-report-summary';
    }
    return $allowed_endpoints;
}
add_filter( 'wp_rest_cache/allowed_endpoints', 'wprc_add_endpoint', 10, 1);
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your code making that custom endpoint "private" though? Unless you've removed the bits that make it available to authenticated users by mistake when you posted your code here?

Comment: @cabrerahector ah yes i did miss it out, apologies. Have edited the question.